# Cannot debug on Z10, STL100-3

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, momentics

I am developing an app on Momentics.

The app runs fine on my STL100-3 model Z10 but I cannot debug the app. When I launch the debug process, it continually terminates.

I get the following error from the console

```
Timed out.
MsgNak received - resending
```

Eventually, this times out. The debug session never starts.

How can I go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems like this when using wireless to debug my apps. When I switched to debugging via USB everything worked much much better.